# Moving image above content on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am using the default css for `media-object` in bootstrap how ever I am wondering how I can achieve the effect of my audio being below the image on mobile.

What it looks like currently. [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZCzP.png)

What I want it to look like. [Demo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msGzt.png)

My current HTML is.

```
<div class="media">
   <a class="pull-left">    
      <img class="media-object" height="150" width="150" src="<?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); echo ''.$feat_image.''; ?>">  
   </a>
   <div class="media-body">
      <header class="section-header">
         <h2 itemprop="name"><a href="http://www.example.com/singles"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
         <div class="stripe-dotted"></div>
      </header>
      <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about using the media-object. The easy way I would do it would be to just use cols. You can have whatever you want your column size to be on regular display then on mobile make sure they both take up the whole 12 cols.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    image
</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    title and controls
</div>
```